# How to restrict string and date values in a Teradata table

Tags: teradata

Is there any way to impose a restriction on a Teradata table fields, something like this

Column Education can only contain: `High School`, `BS`, `MS`, `PhD` and nothing else. If somebody tries to `INSERT` any other string, the `Referential Integrity` mechanism would throw an exception

---

Also, is there any way to impose a restriction to the `DATE` field, such that a newly inserted date must `>= CURRENT_DATE` ?

Thank you experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as any other RDBMS (besides the COMPRESS part, which is Teradata only to save disk space):

```
datecol DATE CHECK(datecol >= CURRENT_DATE)
```

Maybe add a NOT NULL constraint.

```
education VARCHAR(11) CHECK (education IN ('High School', 'BS', 'MS', 'PhD'))
```

In Teradata you should add `COMPRESS ('High School', 'BS', 'MS', 'PhD')`to save disk space.

Of course you could also insert the four values in a table, add a Primary Key and then a Foreign Key referencing that column...